# VBA code for Excel cut and paste

Tags: excel, vba

The user can enter data in that cell:

1. By choosing from a predefined list of options (scrolling a drop down list)
2. By typing in directly the alphanumeric value (all numbers, all letters, or a combination of the two)
3. By doing copy (from other documents) and paste the identifier in that cell

I do not want to give the user the right to perform option 3? Is there a VBA code to accomplish that?

Excel has always had a problem with validations. They work fine when you need someone to choose from a list or enter specific data, but the moment a user copies data from someone else and Pastes in a Validation Cell, it ignores validations and allows it

Comment: see the `worksheet_change` event. you can test the value there and if it is not valid, you can undo the entry.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target = Range("A1") Then
        If Not (Target >= 1 And Target <= 10) Then
            Application.Undo
            MsgBox "Please enter value between 1 to 10", vbOKOnly + vbCritical
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```